# Shortcode is being shown to user instead of a list in wordpress

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, shortcode

```
[child-pages depth="1" sort_column="menu_order"]
```

Shortcode is being shown to user instead of a list in WordPress. I imported my WordPress website from WordPress to a paid domain and ever since then, this problem exists. I am a beginner in WordPress.

Comment: make sure plugin or theme is enabled which is providing this shortcode

Comment: Perhaps the shortcode is used in a plug-in which isn't active or installed at the moment.

Comment: Where is this being placed? If in template or plugin code, you must use `<?php echo do_shortcode('[child-pages depth="1" sort_column="menu_order"]'); ?>` (note `echo`).

Comment: I don't know which plugin is used for this shortcode.

Comment: It's placed in the text editor in pages.

Answer (score 0):

please activate your plugin or install the plugin which is providing this shortcode